# Voltage step up

Tags: transformer, ac

I have a 10 volt AC output from an audio amplifier and I want to amplify it to 20-30 volts.

What device can I use to achieve this?

Comment: A transformer or an amplifier.

Comment: This may sound stupid but it is serous: an audio amplifier. You could add some boost circuit, but that is just the same as an end stage of a normal audio amplifier. Oh and @Andyaka's transformer can do that will only increase voltage, not power.

Comment: what frequency? 20 Hz to 20,000 Hz? or what? what power output?

Comment: " I want to amplify it to 20-30 volts" - why?

Comment: Possibly a transformer is enough, We need to know more about what you are trying to amplify and why?

Comment: I have generated 3 phase sine waves via python programming. This is then converted to a sound file. The peak voltage of this sine wave is approximately 1-1.5 V. It is then fed to an audio amplifier to amplify it to 10 V. Now I want to step up the Voltage to different ma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need higher voltage or higher power?

You don't say, and may not know the difference.

You can use a transformer to convert 10V AC to 20V AC.

The power stays the same, though.  If you want the higher voltage to get a louder output from a speaker, then it won't really help.  (It is more complicated than that, and in some cases actually can help - but not because of the voltage.  I'm not going to go into that.)

If you need more power, then you will need an amplifier with a power supply.  Transformers can't increase power.  Amplifiers can, but they have to get that power from somewhere.

So, figure out what you need (higher voltage or more power.)  From that you can decide if you need a transformer or an amplifier.

---

To help you understand, here's an example:

Say you have a small incandescent light bulb, rated for 10 watts at 20V.

You have an alternator (AC generator) that puts out 1 watt at 10V.

You connect the bulb to the alternator, and spin the alternator at full speed. The bulb lights up, but very dim.

You look at it, and notice the voltage difference. Ah, ha! The bulb needs more voltage.

You ask the EE StackExchange how to get a higher voltage from your 10V AC, and then you go and buy a transformer with twice as many windings on the secondary as on the primary - this will transform your 10V AC to 20V AC.

You hook up your alternator, your transformer, and your light bulb, then spin the alternator at full speed.

Well, damnit.  The bulb is actually **dimmer** with that transformer in there.  Without the bulb, you do get 20V out of the transformer.  With the bulb hooked up, the voltage drops way down low.  You've actually lost power in the transformer, and are getting less than 1 watt to the bulb.

You go away mad, and EE StackExchange looks like a bunch of idiots because the answers you got were wrong.

Well, no.  You asked a question, and got a correct answer.

It just wasn't the answer to the question you should have asked - which was more like "How can I make this 10W light brighter when operated from a 1W alternator?"  That answer would have helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to increase the voltage and not power. I have searched for step up transformers but most of them have a primary rating of atleast 110 V. Need something that can take in 10 V

Comment: The primary rating tells you the **maximum** voltage you can apply.

Comment: There's more to it than that.  You need to **fully** explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am developing a power system testing device prototype. I have generated 3 phase sine waves using python and converted to a sound file. I am using this sound file as input to the audio amplifier. Now I want to step up the Voltage of the amplifier to 20-30V peak.

Comment: Hi, i do not need a specific 20-30 volts step uo. Just need to just increase the input 10 volts to higher magnitude. Please help me